# Prolog code in python with Pyswip outputs "None"

Tags: python, prolog

I installed pyswip package and tried following code:

```
from pyswip import Prolog,Query

prolog = Prolog()
prolog.assertz("minTime(4,Y):-Y>=4")

res = prolog.query("minTime(4,5)")
print(res)
```

but it outputs "None". It should outputs "True" in Swi-Prolog. I want to know how to output "True" in python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you try `help(prolog)` you will find the answer.

The `res` is a Python generator object which it has to be transformed to a Python list, which has to be transformed to Python bool, that is,

```
>>>bool(list(prolog.query("minTime(4,4)")))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

The res you're trying to print is actually a generator object which cannot be printed because the values don't exist they are generated on demand. Simply you can just get the value out of it using the list() function, then typecast it to boolean data type.